# R says a file doesn't exist when it clearly does

Tags: r, file

I'm using R 4.1.3 and Windows 10. I have a directory with 385 PDF files, but somehow R "thinks" 31 of them are missing. I can open those files from Windows Explorer, they are not corrupted. Also, R finds them with the `list.files` function, so much so that I get this:

```r
length(list.files())
[1] 385
sum(file.exists(list.files()))
[1] 354
```

The only possible difference between these 31 "missing" files and the others is that they have the longest names (71-73 characters), but I have another directory with files that have those same names and they get read. Any hints on what the issue is?

Comment: Another directory, with a shorter full path?

Comment: I set the working directory to the path of the problematic files so I could avoid having long path issues. That still didn't work.

Comment: Could you provide the path pattern of your folder and one of the name file concerned by the issue ?

Comment: Here's one example: Laudos/2022-07-20_Hydrobiology/Laboratory Reports/P22055 - Nov-Dec 2015/Zomnast/Zomnast Laboratory Reports/2015-11-25 - D00XY - Ctenosciaena gracilicirrhus 20 - 32798-1-2021-1.pdf

Comment: Does `file.access()` return the same results as `file.exists()`?

Comment: @MrFlick this is the result:
`sum(file.access(list.files()))

[1] -31
`

Comment: That is very odd. Is this on a standard hard-drive folder? Or are you using something like OneDrive or Dropbox for file storage?

Comment: It's a OneDrive folder. Still very odd, since all the other 1200+ files (both in that directory and others from the same OneDrive) don't have the same issue.

Comment: If it's OneDrive, then it probably has to do with the files-on-demand feature. Not sure why it would be selectively only happing in one directory but much of how OneDrive works is a mystery to me. Maybe those are the largest files? Maybe try adjusting that setting: https://www.technorms.com/44301/force-onedrive-store-files-pc-not-just-cloud

Comment: Also not the issue. All the files have either 168 or 169KB and the folder is set to be available offline - meaning that I have a local copy of every file.

Comment: Same problem. The file exists, but R claims it does not on Windows.
DIGESTR_GIF_PATH  <- normalizePath( system.file("extdata", "digestR.gif", package = "digestR") )